# Getting error with null safety operator usage

Tags: dart

```dart
class Person {
  String name;

  Person(this.name);
}

void main() {
  Person? person = Person('Alice'); // Use Person? to declare person as nullable

  // Using the null-aware operator (?.) to access a property
  String? personName = person?.name; // Use String? to declare personName as nullable
  print('Person\'s name: $personName');

  // Attempting to access a property of a null object
  Person? nullPerson; // Declare nullPerson as nullable
  String? nullPersonName = nullPerson?.name; // Use String? to declare nullPersonName as nullable
  print('Null person\'s name: $nullPersonName');
}
```

Showing this error:

```
11:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'Person' which excludes null.
 - 'Person' is from 'switch.dart'.
  String? personName = person?.name; // Use String? to declare personName as nullable
```

I unable to understand this problem. Please help with this error

Answer (score 0):

The warning you are getting is because Dart are smart enough to know that where your have `person?.name` the first place, the `person` variable can't ever be `null` since you have assigned a value to the variable right at the declaration and does not set the variable again to some other value later on before the call.

It does then not matter if you have a nullable type or not since Dart have analyzed that the variable must not be null at the given moment. If Dart would be in any doubt, it would not do this promotion.